# Elements in $\text{GL}(n,q)$ with irreducible characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $x,y\in\text{GL}(n,q)$ be of the same order such that both the characteristic polynomials of $x,y$ are irreducible. Must $x,y$ always be conjugate in $\text{GL}(n,q)$? More restrictly, I am interested in the $2$-dimensional case. But the general answer would be more welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, since the characteristic polynomials are irreducible, they coincide with the minimal polynomials.

Let us deal with $n = 2$. The answer is no in general, but yes in one particular small case.

When $q = 2$, there is only one possible polynomial, that is $x^{2} + x + 1$, then the answer is affirmative, and we are talking elements of order $3$.

Now in general, take an irreducible polynomial $f = x^2 + a x + b$ in $\operatorname{GF}(q)[x]$, then note that its reciprocal $b x^2 + a x + 1$ is also irreducible, so that $g = x^2 + a b^{-1} x + b^{-1}$ is irreducible, and the roots of $g$ are the inverses of the roots of $f$.

If $f \ne g$, then you can take the companion matrices of $f$ and $g$
$$
x = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-b&-a\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
y = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-b^{-1}&-ab^{-1}\end{bmatrix},
$$ 
and these will be non-conjugate elements (the minimal polynomials are different) of the same order (eigenvalues of one matrix are the inverses of eigenvalues of the other).

Now $f \ne g$ if either $a \ne 0$ and $b \ne 1$, or $a = 0$ and $b^{2} \ne 1$.

If $q \ne 2$, such polynomials $f$ always exist, because the norm $N_{\operatorname{GF}(q^{2})/\operatorname{GF}(q)}$ is surjective. In fact, you can always take $b \ne \pm 1$, unless $q = 3$. In this case, just note that the polynomial $f = x^{2} - x - 1$ is irreducible in $\operatorname{GF}(3)[x]$ (and $g = x^2 + x - 1 \ne f$.)

**PS** OK, general $n$ now. I hope the following is correct, as I wrote it a bit hurriedly, and there might be a simpler version.

The discussion above indicates that we are aiming at finding an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $\operatorname{GF}(q)$ which is not *symmetric*, or equivalently an element of $\operatorname{GF}(q^n)$ of degree $n$ over $\operatorname{GF}(q)$ which is not Galois conjugate to its inverse. Now if all elements of $\operatorname{GF}(q^n)$ of degree $n$ over $\operatorname{GF}(q)$ are Galois conjugate to their inverses (actually, it is enough for this to hold for *one* primitive element), this holds for all elements of  $\operatorname{GF}(q^n)$, in particular it holds in all subfields.

Consider first the case $q > 2$. We have seen that in $\operatorname{GF}(q^{2})$ not all elements of degree $2$ are conjugate to their inverses. So we quickly reduce to showing that not all elements of degree $p$ are conjugate to their inverses in $\operatorname{GF}(q^p)$, where $p$ is an *odd* prime. But there are $(q^{p} - q)/p$ monic, irreducible polynomials of degree $p$ over $\operatorname{GF}(q)$ here, and only (**note**: serious misprint corrected) $q^{(p-1)/2}$ symmetric polynomials. (**Addendum**: @user60079 notes in the comments below the much simpler argument that a symmetric polynomial of odd degree $> 1$ has always a root $\pm 1$, and is thus reducible.)

In case $q = 2$, we have also to deal with the possibility that $n = 2^{k}$, with $k \ge 2$. But then it is enough to note that the polynomial $x^{4} + x + 1$ is irreducible in $\operatorname{GF}(2)[x]$, and non-symmetric.

Comment: The answer is also yes when $n=2$ and both $x,y \in {\rm SL}(2,K)$. In that case you do no need to assume that the characteristic polynomials are irreducible, it is sufficient for them to have distinct roots. In that case, the trace of the matrix, and hence also the characteristic and minimal polynomials, are determined by their orders.

Comment: For $\text{SL}(2,K)$ it is easy since the two roots must be mutually reciprocal, and hence determined by the order. @Andreas: Thank you for your detailed answer! I basically get your idea, but I am not sure the last second paragraph. How did you count the monic irreducible polynomials of degree $p$? My idea is: there are $q^{p-1}$ monic polynomials in total. Those reducible polynomials have at least one root, and hence a factor of degree $1$, and the quotient can be any monic polynomial, so $(q-1)q^{p-2}$ choices. This gives $q^{p-1}-(q-1)q^{p-2}=q^{p-2}$, which is different from yours.

Comment: @user60079, you're very welcome! As to your question, there are $q^{p} - q$ elements in $A = \operatorname{GF}(q^p) \setminus \operatorname{GF}(q)$. Since $p$ is prime, each element of $A$ has minimal polynomial of degree $p$ over $\operatorname{GF}(q)$. Each of these minimal polynomials has exactly $p$ roots in $A$, hence the number $(q^{p} - q)/p$ for the number of polynomials. (Note that a polynomial that is reducible over a field $F$ need not have roots in $F$ if the degree is higher than $3$.)

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Oh, yes, I didn't reckon. But is that correct all the $p$ roots are always distinct?

Comment: @user60079, yes, this follows from the general theory of finite fields. The reason is that any irreducible polynomial over $\operatorname{GF}(q)$ of degree $n$ divides $x^{q^{n}} - x$, and by taking the formal derivative you see that the latter polynomial has distinct roots.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Thank you very much for this! I didn't learn much field theory...If you don't mind, could you also explain why $p$ is prime implies each element in $A$ has minimal polynomial of degree $p$?

Comment: @user60079, it's a matter of degrees, sorry, rushing to theatre now, will be more detailed later.

Comment: @user60079, it's matter of applying the so-called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension#The_multiplicativity_formula_for_degrees The degree $\lvert \operatorname{GF}(q^p) : \operatorname{GF}(q) \rvert = p$ is prime, so there no intermediate extensions. So if $a \in A = \operatorname{GF}(q^p) \setminus \operatorname{GF}(q)$, then $(\operatorname{GF}(q))(a) = \operatorname{GF}(q^{p})$, which means that the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\operatorname{GF}(q)$ has degree $p$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, hope you had enjoyed the show and thank you for your passion. Have to bother you again, how did you count those symmetric polynomials? I am thinking on this way but getting different from yours. For each root of the polynomial, its reciprocal must also be a root. So the roots appear as pairs. However, the degree of the polynomial is odd, it indicates the polynomial contains a root that is self-pairing, i.e., 1 or -1, implying the polynomial reducible. What's wrong with my thought?

Comment: @user60079, thanks, there is a serious misprint in the current version, which I am going to correct presently, clearly marking it. It does not affect the result, I guess.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, thanks for the correction. But would my argument suffice, hence no need for counting symmetric polynomials?

Comment: @user60079, I guess you are absolutely right! I will incorporate (with due credit) your argument in my answer.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, just one more question. I was wondering if any element in $\text{GF}(q^m)\setminus\text{GF}(q^n)$ only correspond exactly one irreducible polynomial over $\text{GF}(q^n)$? I believe I can show this is true for the case $\text{GF}(q^p)\setminus\text{GF}(q)$. This is why we can count the irreducible polynomials like that. This sounds like a bit off-topic, but hope you can help.

Comment: @user60079, all monic irreducible polynomials in $\operatorname{GF}(q^n)[x]$ of degree dividing $m/n$ will have all of their roots in $\operatorname{GF}(q^m)$, and these roots will be distinct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(X)=X^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\ldots +a_0$ be the common characteristic polynomial.
Select a nonzero vector $v\in\mathbb F_q^n$.
Then $v, xv,\ldots , x^{n-1}v$ are linearly independent beacuse any linear dependance $\sum c_i\cdot x^iv=0$ would translate into a polynomial $\sum c_iX^i$ of degree $\le n-1$ that is a factor of $f$.
Hence $v, xv,\ldots , x^{n-1}v$ are a basis of $\mathbb F_q^n$.
On the other hand, we have $x^nv = -(a_{n-1}x^{n-1}v+\ldots + a_0)$. Hence the matrix of $x$ with respect to $v, xv,\ldots , x^{n-1}v$ as basis is
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&\cdots&0&-a_0\\1&0&\cdots& 0&-a_1\\0&1&\cdots&0&-a_2\\
\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\0&0&\cdots &1&-a_{d-1}\end{pmatrix} $$
We can do the same with respect to $y$ and since chosing a basis is the same as conjugation, $x$ and $y$ are conjugate.

---

Note that nothing special about finite fields was used, i.e. the result holds in $GL(n,F)$ for any $n$ and any field $F$.

Comment: I may be reading the question wrong, but OP appears to be requiring the two elements (which have the same order) to have characteristic polynomials that are both irreducible, but not necessarily equal.